Mother sees girl on beach, takes her in
Hopefully someone can help. Alright, so I saw this movie toward the end, but it left me wondering how it all started.
From what I saw, this young woman was wandering around somewhere by the beach, she runs into a mother (the mother was wearing a black and white stripped long sleeve shirt) and her toddler and the mother sees the wandering girl and feels sorry for her and decides to let her in the home. The young girl sees the toddler then goes to the bathroom and uses it, (#2) then takes the toothbrush and swishes it around in the toilet than puts it back.
Later in the movie there was a yellow tarp or tent and the woman with the child were in it. The young girl decides to stab the mother to death. Then as the movie ended I see the young girl wearing the same shirt that the mother wore before with the stripes, and she is holding the toddler while the toddler is crying, but they are on a boat or ferry leaving. It was weird and it was a foreign film I saw on HBO or SHO in 1998 .Thanks

@Richard OP's after a foreign film, that they saw in 1998 (I edited it a bit).

This is Francois Ozon's short, seaside thriller See the Sea from 1997.

The Englishwoman Sasha lives on Île d'Yeu near France with her ten-month-old daughter and her husband, who is often away for business. One day, when Sasha is home alone, the drifter Tatiana appears at Sasha's door and asks her for permission to pitch her tent in the garden. At first reserved and reluctant, Sasha eventually allows her this and both women begin to develop a relationship with each other. Sasha decides to go shopping and leaves Sioffra in Tatiana's care. When, upon her return, she finds everything in order, she finally invites Tatiana inside her house, even though she is irritated by Tatiana's unusual behavior.
When Sasha's husband comes home on the following day, he finds an empty house. In the tent behind the house lies Sasha bound and dead. Tatiana holds the crying Sioffra on a ferry, which is leaving the island.

The toothbrush in the toilet scene is in there as well. Here's the trailer:




Thank very much for your assistance.I do appreciate. it. :)
